# Antivirus for Windows that has the option to not delete a specific file it thinks is a virus/threat, even when I move the file around

Tags: windows, antivirus

I am looking for an antivirus for Windows that has the option to not delete a specific file it thinks is a virus/threat, even when I move the file around. I read  that Windows Defender and many other antiviruses do not have this feature:

> You have run into a limitation of Windows Defender. I should add that most AV applications have similar restrictions to their exclusion list. – [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) [14 hours ago](https://superuser.com/q/1823954/116475)

Any license and price is fine, but I want a GUI and I use Windows 10.